# Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject with "invalid ID"

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, document-library, administration, pnp-powershell

After I successfully call `$f=Get-PnpFile -Url $Url` if I invoke `Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $f -Property Versions` I get an error that the object ID is invalid.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this PnP PowerShell snippet with `Get-PnPFileVersion` cmdlet:

```
# Connect to SharePoint Online site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite" -Interactive

# Get file
$f = Get-PnPFile -Url $Url

# Get file versions
$fileversions = Get-PnPFileVersion -Url $Url
```

Make sure to run this script using full control permissions on the site and file/document library.

**Documentation**: [Get-PnPFileVersion](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPFileVersion.html)

Comment: This gets me "Access Denied"...

Comment: Did you use Connect-PnPOnline first? What permissions you have on the file/library?